# Issue with "try?" and AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, swift2

I am having the following issue with AVAudioPlayer:

```
import Foundation   //Needed for dispatch_once_t
import AVFoundation //Needed to play sounds

class PlayStartSong {

    var song: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var songStarted: Bool = false

    class var sharedInstance: PlayStartSong {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: PlayStartSong? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = PlayStartSong()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    func prepareAudios() {

        var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("start-2.0", ofType: "mp3")
        song = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))    //Error Here
        song.prepareToPlay()

        song.numberOfLoops = -1 //Makes the song play repeatedly
    }
}
```

On the line that assigns the value of the variable "song" in the "prepareAudios" function, I am getting the following error after converting to Swift 2.0:

> Value of optional type 'AVAudioPLayer?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

However, upon using the suggested fix, it is telling me to remove the exclamation point I just added. What is the exact issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `try?` as you intended your `song` variable has to be an Optional:

```
class PlayStartSong {

    var song: AVAudioPlayer?
    var songStarted: Bool = false

    class var sharedInstance: PlayStartSong {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: PlayStartSong? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = PlayStartSong()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    func prepareAudios() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("start-2.0", ofType: "mp3")
        song = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
        song?.prepareToPlay()
        song?.numberOfLoops = -1 //Makes the song play repeatedly
    }
}
```

To not make it an Optional, you would use `try` inside `do catch`:

```
func prepareAudios() {
    do {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("start-2.0", ofType: "mp3")
        song = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
        song.prepareToPlay()
        song.numberOfLoops = -1 //Makes the song play repeatedly
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Also, if you are *absolutely* sure that creating the AVAudioPlayer instance will always succeed, you can ignore "do catch" by using `try!`:

```
func prepareAudios() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("start-2.0", ofType: "mp3")
    song = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
    song.prepareToPlay()
    song.numberOfLoops = -1 //Makes the song play repeatedly
}
```

Comment: Great answer - very thorough. BTW, the cast to `NSError` is unnecessary: `catch { print(error) }` will give identical output.

Comment: Thank you very much. Updated the answer because the cast was indeed unnecessary.