# Swift Error is not handled and not marked with try

Tags: xcode, swift

I currently run into a error with that bit of code since i updated Xcode

> {!}Call can throw, but is not marked with 'try' and the error is not
>   handled

```
   let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("jump", withExtension: "caf")
            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL!, fileTypeHint: nil)
            audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
            audioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with "try?" and AVAudioPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805153/issue-with-try-and-avaudioplayer)

Comment: the problem is this answer did not work for my code?
I did tried it but run in several errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error-Handling in Swift-Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010569/error-handling-in-swift-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is now throwable so you have handle it this way:

```
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL!, fileTypeHint: nil)
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    audioPlayer.play()
} catch {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 2,  you should be handling exceptions. Below code should fix your problem:

```
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL!, fileTypeHint: nil)
} catch (_) {

}
```

Comment: Please post a reason for down voting. I did not post complete code but surely pointed out the cause of error here.

Comment: This is a correct answer as it fixes the error you were getting.

Comment: Indeed, this is a good answer in that it shows how to fix the problem without providing complete, drop-in code. (voted).